# Adding icons to tabs using Easy Responsive Tabs from WP

Tags: tabs, icons

I cant find anything to answer me this. How can I add icons to the title of my ERT tabs? ERT generates a shortcode which I have added to home php file and it works beautifully but how can I edit the shortcode so that the title tab includes an icon? code looks like this in the PHP:

```
'<?php echo do_shortcode('[restabs alignment="osc-tabs-center" pills="nav-pills" responsive="true" icon="true" text="Next" tabcolor="#ffffff" tabheadcolor="#2C3E51" seltabcolor="#2C3E51" seltabheadcolor="#ffffff" tabhovercolor="#f7933b"]
[restab title="(NEED ICON HERE)OUR WORK" active="active"]
<table style="width: 100%; border: none; margin-top: 0px; font-size: 10px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Content</td>
<td>Content</td>
<td>Content</td>
<td>Content</td>
<td>Content</td>
</tr>
[/restab]
[/restabs]'); ?>'
```

Comment: Does ERT have a place to add a custom class to each tab?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the plugin's output and unfortunately there is not super easy way to select the tabs anchor link with css.

If you go into the ERT Settings you can set a custom class for the tab group.  I set it to "myclass" for the example.  Then you can use the following css to select tabs individually and use css `a:before` with `content: url('myicon.png');` to insert your icon.

For example to select the second tab (li)...

```
div.myclass li:nth-child(2) a:before {content: url('icon.png');}
```

For the first tab you can use `:first-child` then use `:nth-child` thereafter